# SGPLOT Procedure STYLEATTRS Statement

Tags: sas

[Official document](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67909/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1dt33l6a6epk6n1chtynsgsjgit.htm) said 6 style options are  available

```
BACKCOLOR=color

DATACOLORS=(color-list)

DATACONTRASTCOLORS=(color-list)

DATALINEPATTERNS=(line-pattern-list)

DATASYMBOLS=(marker-symbol-list)

WALLCOLOR=color
```

However, when I try something like below

```
proc sgplot data=test;
 styleattrs backcolor=vpal;
...
run;
```

Error messages pop up:

```
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, DATACOLORS, DATACONTRASTCOLORS, DATALINEPATTERNS, DATASYMBOLS.  
ERROR 202-322: The option or parameter is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

Is it a SAS version problem? I'm using EG 6.1.

The main reason I want to use this option is to have within procedure control on graph background color. I have 4 graphs in one page in PDF and I want to control the background color for each graph with macro variable based on some criteria. 
So changing the ODS output style doesn't work for me - it changes EVERY graph background.

Comment: What's your SAS version, not EG version. Use %put &syslver; and check your log. It's highly likely your on an earlier version of SAS. Also, I doubt vpal is a valid colour. If you post the full log it will highlight exactly where the issue is, which would be helpful to see.

Comment: No, I meant SYSVLONG - need full version :)

Comment: @Reeza `AUTOMATIC SYSVER 9.4     
AUTOMATIC SYSVLONG 9.04.01M1P120413
AUTOMATIC SYSVLONG4 9.04.01M1P12042013`

Comment: BACKCOLOR and wallcolor appear to have been added later, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BACKCOLOR is only available as of SAS 9.4 TS1M3. You have TS1M1.

See the Note in the documentation you linked to under BACKCOLOR.

[image: Documentation Note]

Comment: Thanks Reeza. Do you know any other way to control the individual graph b/c besides this option?

Comment: You can probably do it using GTL, design a template that sets background colour as a dynamic variable. I don't have time to mock up an example but that's probably the route I'd suggest.

Comment: thanks. But I think template from GTL applies to the whole ods output?

Comment: Not a style template, a graph template that gets used with proc sgrender. In this you can override the style defaults. It's just tricky sometimes finding the options you need...and more code. http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/363-2013.pdf

Comment: Usually GTL has these sorts of things before they expose them in the main SGPLOT so that wouldn't surprise me.  It's possible that someone could run the SGPLOT in 9.4 TS1M3 and show you the GTL....